# How to check SQLiteDatabase .replace() if success?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android application I'm using `SQLiteDatabase`, I use `.replace()` for inserting/updating a row. But when I try to `Select` the whole row without conditions it always returns `null`. I'm wondering how can I check if it is successfully added or updated in my database?

Comment: you can check the its return value. It is != -1 if replace was successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` or `replaceOrThrow` will return a long value that is the row ID of new row, or -1 if an error occurred.
So you can check it to know replace successful or not

```
long result = db.replace(tableName, nullColumnHack, values);
if(result != -1){
    // replace successful 
}
```

If you want to see the error message you can use `replaceOrThrow`

```
try {
  long result = db.replaceOrThrow(tableName, nullColumnHack, values);
    if(result != -1){
        // replace successful 
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: can I also use this for `select` ? if I successfully get a row?

Comment: when you use `select` it will return a `Cursor`, simply check the `Cursor` value to know  you have data in sqlitedatabase or not

Comment: Thanks! I found out that my `select` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use changes() after insert, update or delete  to get number of rows afected.

Take a look at documentation:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes